# If P is prime then $\frac{2}{P}=1/M+1/N$ where $M$ and $N$ are integers and $M$ does NOT equal $N$. Also prove that this representation is unique.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If P is prime then $\frac{2}{P}=1/M+1/N$ where $M$ and $N$ are integers and $M$ does NOT equal $N$. Also prove that this representation is unique. If so, $M$ and $N$ can be expressed in terms of $P$.

Comment: here prime $p>2$

Comment: For odd prime p there is one unordered pair solution in POSITIVE integers,but there is also a solution with one positive ,one negative.See Andre Nicolas answer, and my comment after it

Answer (score 5):

Let $p$ be an odd prime. We show that there is exactly one solution in distinct *positive* integers.

We want to solve $2MN=p(M+N)$, or equivalently $4MN-2p(M+N)=0$. Rewrite as 
$$(2M-p)(2N-p)=p^2.$$
There are only two solutions: (i) each term is $p$, or (ii) one is $1$ and the other is $p^2$. Case (i) gives $M=N=p$.

In Case (ii) we may without loss of generality assume that $2M-p=1$ and $2N-p=p^2$. Now solve for $M$ and $N$.

**Remark:** If we allow one of the integers to be negative, we get, as pointed out by user254665, an additional solution by taking $2M-p=-1$ and $2N-p=-p^2$.

Comment: Not able to understand

Comment: I added a little. If you can point to what you don't understand, I can add more, in a comment or as an addition to the answer.

Comment: Or one term is -1 and the other is $-p^2$. Which gives a second solution.It did not  specify positive integers,just integers. I like your method.

Answer (score 2):

For any integer $x$, consider the identity:
$$\frac2P = \frac1x+\frac{2x-P}{xP}$$

we need the numerator of the second fraction to be $1$, which is possible only with the choice $x=\frac12(P+1)$.  You have your $M = x, N = xP$.

Comment: it's unclear to me why $2x-P$ **has to** be $1$ and not $2x-P$ divides $xP$.

Comment: How we'll show uniqueness part

Comment: $x=\frac{p^2+p}2$...

Comment: @QuangHoang That's just switching $M, N$.

Comment: still, that invalidates your argument: why $xp=k(2x-p)$ implies $x|p$?